# What is CreatePerOwinContext replacement in AspNetCore?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

What is the `CreatePerOwinContext` replacement, if any, in AspNetCore?

I'm trying to migrate the Asp.Net Identity samples to AspNet Core, and finding that the legacy? package that provides the `CreatePerOwinContext` extension method is not compatible with Asp.Net Core framework.

Answer (score 4):

After some digging...it seems that `CreatePerOwinContext` was primarily part of a dependency injection mechanism.

Microsoft.AspNetCore 1.0.0 supports dependency injection as a first-class citizen.

https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/dependency-injection.html

Extensions are available for most of the common Identity services that are required.   For example, below is a comparison of the `CreatePerOwinContext` compared to the `IServiceCollection`

**IServiceCollection (AspNetCore 1.0.0)**

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    }
}
```

**CreatePerOwinContext (obsolete)**

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
    }
}
```