# IApplicationbuilder does not contain definition for CreatePerOwinContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, owin, identity

I am just converting an existing Mvc application into .Net Core now here is the problem when creating perOwinContext

```
  app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
```

[image]

because no extension method of this class **IApplicationBuilder** contains this method.
Are there any alternatives to this in .Net Core?

I have also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38810310/what-is-createperowincontext-replacement-in-aspnetcore) but can't figure out how to resolve this case?

Comment: You don't need this at all if you've set things up in `ConfigureServices` (e.g. using `AddIdentity`).

Comment: @Krik Larkin i am unable to figure out how to convert this into AddIdentity

Comment: The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio) have a detailed explanation of setting this up in ASP.NET Core. It might be worth following through the tutorial in a sample project so you can see first-hand how things are different.

Answer (score -2):

It's belong to **Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin** package
Please install **Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin** by Nuget Package Manager.

Comment: this is ok only if you are using IAppBuilder class.

Comment: What do you mean? The **Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin** just has the **CreatePerOwinContext** extension method for **IAppBuilder**, so no problem.

Comment: as I have already mentioned I am working on .Net Core not Mvc , .Net has IApplicationbuilder class not IAppBuilder

Comment: Oh, my mistake. So remove that line.