# What Is The Alternate Of AuthenticationManager In .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, owin, owin-middleware

I am working on .Net Core Project now I need AuthenticationManager for interface
**IAuthenticationManager**

According to Microsoft [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.authentication.authenticationmanager?view=aspnetcore-2.2) has obsolote.

To get ApplicationSignInManager I have this method

```
      private ApplicationSignInManager getSignInManager(ApplicationUserManager manager, IAuthenticationManager auth)
    {
        return new ApplicationSignInManager(manager, auth);

    }
```

**ApplicationSignInManager**

```
 public class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser, string>
{
    public ApplicationSignInManager(ApplicationUserManager userManager, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
        : base(userManager, authenticationManager)
    {
    }
    public static ApplicationSignInManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationSignInManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        return new ApplicationSignInManager(context.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>(), context.Authentication);
    }
}
```

This does work in Mvc project due to CreatePerOwinContext which is called using

```
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);
```

[image]

But how can I activate this class in .Net Core?

Have also learned here that this CreateOwinContext is obsolote in .Net core [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38810310/what-is-createperowincontext-replacement-in-aspnetcore) but can't figure out how to call create method of **ApplicationSignInManager** ?

Answer (score 11):

[`AuthenticationManager`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.authentication.authenticationmanager?view=aspnetcore-2.2) was a utility to perform authentication related actions through the [`HttpContext.Authentication`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpcontext.authentication?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_HttpContext_Authentication) property. So you for example called `HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync(…)` to sign in a user.

This access has been deprecated for quite a while now. There are now [extensions methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticationhttpcontextextensions?view=aspnetcore-2.2) directly on `HttpContext` that serve this purpose:

- [`HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticationhttpcontextextensions.authenticateasync?view=aspnetcore-2.2)
- [`HttpContext.ChallengeAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticationhttpcontextextensions.challengeasync?view=aspnetcore-2.2)
- [`HttpContext.ForbidAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticationhttpcontextextensions.forbidasync?view=aspnetcore-2.2)
- [`HttpContext.GetTokenAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticationhttpcontextextensions.gettokenasync?view=aspnetcore-2.2)
- [`HttpContext.SignInAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticationhttpcontextextensions.signinasync?view=aspnetcore-2.2)
- [`HttpContext.SignOutAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticationhttpcontextextensions.signoutasync?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

So now you just need access to the current `HttpContext` and you can call the authentication actions directly, without needing the `AuthenticationManager` indirection.

As for OWIN related things, note that ASP.NET Core does not use OWIN but created a completely new system. That one is based on OWIN, so you can find familiar things, but still fundamentally different. So you will need to get accustomed to [the new authentication system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/?view=aspnetcore-3.0).