# AuthenticationManager.RegisteredModules not returning anything

Tags: authentication, .net-core

I have inherited a .net framework console app that uses a custom authenticator to connect to a third party API. It works fine and authenticates against the API.

I have migrated this code to .NET Core as I need it part of our main application. The conversion has gone well accept i still couldn't get the authentication to work.

Below is the code that run to register a new authentication method. It's pretty standard.

```
    private static AuthenticationModule registerAuthenticationModule(Uri loginServerUrl)
    {
        IEnumerator registeredModules = AuthenticationManager.RegisteredModules;
        AuthenticationModule authenticationModule;

        while (registeredModules.MoveNext())
        {
            object current = registeredModules.Current;
            if (current is AuthenticationModule)
            {
                authenticationModule = (AuthenticationModule)current;
                if (authenticationModule.LoginServerUrl.Equals(loginServerUrl))
                {
                    return authenticationModule;
                }
            }
        }

        authenticationModule = new AuthenticationModule(loginServerUrl);
        AuthenticationManager.Register(authenticationModule);
        displayRegisteredModules();
        
        return authenticationModule;
    }
```

In the .net framework version, AuthenticationManager.RegisteredModules returns 5 standard authentication methods e.g. digest, basic. When i run this within .NET Core it returns none. In fact the list that should store the modules also doesn't exist.

When i then add the new authentication module using AuthenticationManager.Register nothing happens. There is no additional authentication module on the list (which still doesn't exist).

Here is the .NET Framework list showing 5 standard methods plus the custom one at the bottom.

[image]

Here is the .NET Core list.

[image]

There is very little documentation on the web around this and this is not my area of expertise. Can anyone please give some suggestions as to why this might not be working in .net core. I suspect if i can get this populated it will fix my issues.

Answer (score 0):

Hope the below link would help you to sort the issue with.net core conversion.

[What Is The Alternate Of AuthenticationManager In .Net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58128901/what-is-the-alternate-of-authenticationmanager-in-net-core)

Cheers