# Updating Claims Value in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, claims

In the account login, I added values to the claims as

```
 // Initialization.    
 var claims = new List < Claim > ();
 try {
   // Setting    
   TextInfo textInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).TextInfo;
   string nme = textInfo.ToTitleCase(Name.ToLower());
   string surN = textInfo.ToTitleCase(surName.ToLower());
   claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, Name));
   claims.Add(new Claim("surName", surN));
   claims.Add(new Claim("Name", nme));
   claims.Add(new Claim("Customer_Id", Customer_Id));
   claims.Add(new Claim("User_Id", UserId));
   claims.Add(new Claim("TimeZone", timeZone));
   var claimIdenties = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
   var ctx = Request.GetOwinContext();
   var authenticationManager = ctx.Authentication;
   // Sign In.    
   authenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() {
     IsPersistent = false
   }, claimIdenties);
   var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

   var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
   Thread.CurrentPrincipal = claimsPrincipal;

 } catch (Exception ex) {
   // Info    
   throw ex;
```

Now I want to update the Claims value in "Customer_Id" with a new value in another controller.

How do I update this claim?

Comment: Note that the authentication manager, accessed with `GetOwinContext().Authentication` is [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58129882/941240), the `HttpContext::SignInAsync` should be used instead.

Answer (score 2):

I recently needed to achieve something similar. Add your claims to the IdentityModel where it says `Add custom user claims here`

```
var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
   userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, Name));
   userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("surName", surN));
   userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("Name", nme));
   userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("Customer_Id", Customer_Id));
   userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("User_Id", UserId));
   userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("TimeZone", timeZone));
```

Then insert this line just under the class definition at the top of the controller that you want to access the claims.

```
ApplicationUserManager userManager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
```

Now to modify the claim in any of your controller actions

```
ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync("your username");
user.Customer_Id = "your new id";
await userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
```